# Android: Pass value from activity to broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android

First of all, sorry for my bad grammar. I am developing Auto Reply Message Application using broadcastreceiver i have problem with when I can receive value from activity to broadcastreceiver, the Auto Reply won't work. But if I'm not receive value from Activity, it's working. this is my activity code, I put it in onSensorChanged()

```
Intent i = new Intent("my.action.string");
i.putExtra("apaan", lala);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

and this is my broadcastreceiver class

```
public class AutoReply extends BroadcastReceiver{

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.i("message", "Broadcast Received: " +action);

    if (action.equals(SMS_RECEIVED) && action.equals("my.action.string")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String state = bundle.getString("apaan");

        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            String isiSMS = "", noPengirim = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                isiSMS = sms[i].getMessageBody();//mengambil isi pesan dari pengirim
                noPengirim = sms[i].getOriginatingAddress();//mengambil no pengirim
            }

            String message = state;//isi balasan autoreplay

            SmsManager smsSend = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsSend.sendTextMessage(noPengirim, null, message, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoReply" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="my.action.string" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action will never be both `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` and `my.action.string`.

Change this:

```
if (action.equals(SMS_RECEIVED) && action.equals("my.action.string")) {
```

To this:

```
if (action.equals(SMS_RECEIVED) || action.equals("my.action.string")) {
```

In addition, you're not sending `pdus` in the manually created Intent, so when you call `bundle.get("pdus")` it will return null.  Then when you call `pdus.length` it will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but when I try it, I got another error at my broadcastreceiver class in line final smsMessage[] sms = .....  . it says that Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: That's because you're not sending "pdus", so when you call `bundle.get("pdus")` it returns null.  Then when you call `pdus.length` it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. But what should I do to fix the error?